# find the first occurrence of a specific value in different groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have this toy dataframe that I was have a column of accuracy values and another column of group ID. I am hoping that I can get the position index, for each group, that the accuracy value gets up to 0.9. Could anyone help out, please?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"acc":[0.6,0.9,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.9],
                   "id":[1,1,1, 2,2,2]})
```

[image]

Ideally, I want it to return index position 1, 4 in this case.

Comment: `df.index[df.acc==0.9]`?

Comment: you are right, but maybe I gave a poor example which I updated it. Since I want to pick the first occurrence of 0.9 in each group, in this case I want it to return 1, 4. ideas pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `drop_duplicates`

```
idx = df[df.acc.eq(0.9)].drop_duplicates('id').index
Out[64]: Int64Index([1, 4], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: thank you, it works! Would you mind unpacking the code a bit for me? Does `.acc.eq(0.9)` find the first value equal to 0.9? and does the `drop_duplicates` drop the unwanted rows?

Comment: drop_duplicates will only keep the first not duplicate value per id , which is first index match the value 0.9 @EdwardLin

Comment: nice, what if  we want to add another condition, like threshold for another indicator, say time spent, how do we write the conditions?

Answer (score 1):

The following code finds, for each `id`, the earliest index at which `acc` exceeds `threshold`:

```
threshold = 0.9
df[df['acc'] >= threshold]\
    .sort_index()\
    .drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep='first')\
    .index
```

Not sure what the difference in performance between these two approaches is, but another way to achieve the same results would be:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x[x['acc'] >= threshold].index.min()))
```

By sorting on `acc` in line 3, we can find, for each `id`, the index where `acc` first crosses `threshold`:

```
threshold = 0.9
df[df['acc'] >= threshold]\
    .sort_values(by='acc', ascending=True)\
    .drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep='first')\
    .index
```

Comment: nice, what if we want to add another condition, like threshold for another indicator, say time spent, how do we write the conditions?

Comment: (Just realized I can't enter multiple lines in comments...) My first guess would be to try modifying that filtering operation, e.g., `df[(df['var1'] >= threshold_1) & (df['var2'] <= threshold_2)].sort_index().drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep='first').index`